# This computer doesn't have VT-x/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

Tags: virtualbox, bios, virtualization

I have a Windows 8.1 Dell laptop with virtualization enabled. Below is the picture of intel processor identification utility.

I have Fedora 24 installed in my virtual box. It also has virtualization enabled.

[image]

When I run the cat `/proc/cpuinfo | grep 'vmx\|svm'` and minikube start command, it display below error message and I am not able to proceed.

Any suggestion on this how to resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032), so the guest VM will not support VMX or SVM even though the host machine does.  You can't run a VM inside a VM.

From your screenshot, it looks like you're trying to run Kubernetes in your VirtualBox VM.  I'm not a Kubernetes expert, but my understanding is that it's meant to manage a cluster of virtual machines.  The lack of nested virtualization means you can't run the cluster within a VM; you have to install it on real hardware.  Basically, Kubernetes is something you'd use *instead* of VirtualBox, as a different way of creating and managing your VMs.

If you really need to run Kubernetes in a VM, [VMware Workstation and Player seem to support nested virtualization](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970).

Comment: It seems, as of VirtualBox 6.1.0, nested virtualization is now [supported](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032#comment:163).

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyla0.png)

Try this one in Bios settings and re-run minikube start

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  The author was attempting to enable hardware virtualization within a VirtualBox virtual machine, VirtualBox, does not support nest virtualization.  The author clearly indicated the VT-x option did not exist in the firmware settings.